# Cannot create connection using ssh to godaddy server

Tags: unix, ssh, rsa

Problem :

Trying to login to godaddy server from Mac Terminal to upload certain images (using script). While connecting to server using ssh i am getting following error

```
ssh admin@pricereview.in
```

output

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

On more debugging ran

```
ssh -v admin@pricereview.in
```

Output

```
ankits-MacBook-Air:ssh ankit$ ssh -v pricereview.in
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pricereview.in [166.62.27.64] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ankit/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Also checked:

```
ankits-MacBook-Air:ssh ankit$ ls -ltr ~/.ssh/
total 40
-rw-------@ 1 ankit  staff   412 Jan 24 11:55 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------@ 1 ankit  staff  1766 Jan 24 11:55 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 ankit  staff   620 Jan 24 11:55 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 ankit  staff   751 Jan 24 11:55 id_dsa
-rw-------  1 ankit  staff   412 Jan 24 12:03 authorized_keys
ankits-MacBook-Air:ssh ankit$
```

settings on the godaddy server :

id_rsa ---> public key and private key present

Manually imported the id_rsa by copying it from mac.

Aim: The main aim is to upload images from mac  to server/website using shell script.

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/enable-ssh-4942

Comment: @jakuje already tried.

Comment: ssh questions don't belong on stackoverflow, they belong on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Using ftp shell script, created shell script and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with primary ftp user?